# What kind of cache to use for variable cost and moving maxima?

Tags: recursion, caching

I have to compute certain values `f(n,{},{})` which depend on several other `f(m,{a1,a2,...,ap},{b1,b2,...,bq})` with `m<n` and each `ai`, `bj`, `p`, `q` smaller than `m`. These in turn need other similar values with still smaller `m'`, etc.

The smaller the `m` the quicker can I recompute these. Moreover, observing function calls I see that the `m` for most frequently needed values grows with `n` approximately like `n/3`.

I tried to just cache everything but ran out of memory very quickly, around `n=80`, and I need to reach `n=200`. If I do not cache anything, already around `n=50` I needed about a day, and the time grows exponentially (with a relatively small exponent, but still...)

In such circumstances, what type of cache would be most optimal? I mean cache types like mru, mfu, etc. or some more clever modifications which I know nothing about.